# How to delete a specific warning gcc

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

i have a specific warning that i would like to delete/ hide and then enable it just after. Do you have any idea how can i do that without deleting all the other warnings?

this is the warning i am getting

```
warning: enumeration value 'EtatCCSortie' not handled in switch [-Wswitch]
```

and i dont need to actually use that state in the switch (it's a state machine). I have a way to noy get this warning anymore which is by adding the state to the switch like this:

```
while (etatsImprimanteCasImpressionPeriodique != EtatIPSortie)
{
         switch (etatsImprimanteCasChangementCartouche)
         {
               ....
               case EtatCCSortie:
               break;
```

But i don't have to add it because it will never execute (while !=). that's why i am looking for a way to unable this specific warning and then enable it just after this switch.

Ps:i am aware of the importance of warnings and i only need a way to delete it.

Comment: Do you have an explicit `default:` branch? If not, insert one, the compiler will implement it in any case. Better be explicit.

Comment: Makes more robust code... "value will never happen" - "famous last words".

Comment: Please post a full [MCVE].

Comment: The `while` has another value than the `case`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [diagnostic pragmas](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html):

```
enum somenum {
    EtatIPSortie,
    EtatCCSortie,
};
int etatsImprimanteCasImpressionPeriodique;
enum somenum etatsImprimanteCasChangementCartouche;

void func() {
    while (etatsImprimanteCasImpressionPeriodique != EtatIPSortie)
    {
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wswitch"
            switch (etatsImprimanteCasChangementCartouche)
            {
                case EtatCCSortie:
                break;
            }
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using compiler specific `#pragma` you should just add a `default: break;` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Using:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-W<replace_this_with_the_warning>"
```